# django using cached database query problem

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have django application witch save traffic logs .
the problem is when we refresh page doesnt show new logs its like query set cached some where.
I made a manager to return last n log.

this is my code

```
from django.db.models import Manager 

class LogMannager(Manager):
    def _last(self,num,server=None,camera=None):
        if  camera:
            return self.get_queryset().filter(camera=camera).order_by('-id')[:num]
        elif server:
            return self.get_queryset().filter(server=server).order_by('-id')[:num]
        else:
            ret = self.get_queryset().all().order_by('-id')[:num]
            print(ret)
            return ret
```

the server is in production and using uwsgi

update:

this is where am i using :

```
class MainKioskView(MainMixin, generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'monitoring/main_kiosk.html'
    log = Log.objects._last(30)
    all_server = Server.objects.all()
    servers = [[server, Log.objects.filter(server=server).last(), ActiveCamera.objects.filter(server=server)] for server
               in all_server]
    extra_context = {'logs': log, 'servers': servers}
```

Comment: Can you share where you are calling this method?

Answer (score 0):

Once a queryset is evaluated it stores the result as a kind of cache so that iterating over it multiple times doesn't trigger a DB call each time. `log` and `extra_context` are class attributes so every instance of your view gets the same, already evaluated, queryset on every request.

You need to create a new queryset each time and remove these class attributes. The same goes for `servers` too most likely

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context_data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context_data['logs'] = Log.objects._last(30)
    return context_data
```